# Data Feed in XML failed

Tags: xml, cloud, datafeed

We use a cloud based software which gets data fed everyday. The feed is in XML format, directly sent from the Bank to the software. For whatever reason, the feed sometimes failed and that caused us delays. Now I want to get the XML file and open it up to check why. But as I said, it is feeding directly to a cloud based software. Any idea how to get the actual XML? Thanks

Comment: I think you should ask your bank; not the internet ;)

Comment: Hi Robin, I agree. One thing I dont like cloud based software is, we do not have control. Thank you.